# mirroring traffic with iptables doesn't work

Tags: iptables, mirror

I want to mirror specific traffic to ip 192.168.200.1
I use the following solution:

[Mirror Port via iptables](https://superuser.com/questions/753294/mirror-port-via-iptables)

However, when I enter following command, this error occurs:

```
iptables –I PREROUTING -t mangle -j ROUTE --gw 192.168.200.1 --tee

iptables v1.4.12: unknown option "--gw"
```

When I replace "--gw" with "-gateway", like this:

```
iptables –I PREROUTING -t mangle -j ROUTE -gateway 192.168.200.1 --tee
```

this error occur:

```
iptables v1.4.12:multiple -j flag not allowed
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j TEE --gateway 192.168.200.1
```

For that version of iptables -j ROUTE doesn't work.